# GetArgument<T> does not parse

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, graphql

I am using `GetArgument<T>` method to convert input arguments from GraphQL query, where T is an input class (`InputSearchCriteriaClass`). While I see arguments in the watch/debugger, it is incorrectly parsed into class `T`.

**Input class:**

```
public class InputSearchCriteriaClass
{
  public InputSearchCriteriaClass()
  {
    carrierGases = new List<int>();
  }
  public List<int> carrierGases { get; set; }
}
```

**I am using the following corresponding type for this class:**

```
public class SearchCriteriaInputType: InputObjectGraphType<InputSearchCriteriaClass>
{
  public SearchCriteriaInputType()
  {
    Name = "inputSearch";
    Field(x => x.carrierGases, type: typeof(ListGraphType<IntGraphType>)).Description("List of available carrier gases");
   }
}
```

**The following code is used to process query:**

```
Field<IntGraphType>("getInstrumentsCount",
 arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<SearchCriteriaInputType>
 {
   Name = "inputSearch",
   Description = "text"
 }),
 resolve: _ =>
 {
   var id = _.GetArgument<SearchCriteriaInputType>("inputSearch");
   return 1;
  });
```

**I am trying to execute the following query:**

```
query
{
 getInstrumentsCount(inputSearch: {
  carrierGases:[1, 2],
 })
}
```

That `id` in resolver has all zero arguments. Are there any suggestions how to parse an input class correctly?

Comment: You should read [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the only way it is working is via JObject in the resolver:

```
JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(_.Arguments["inputSearch"]);
var o = obj.ToObject<InputSearchCriteriaClass>();
```

Comment: Based on my tests, `.GetArgument<T>` is working only when `T` is a scalar variable, but not an object.